# fi ligature not shown in output

Tags: fonts, pdftex, font-encodings

Words with fi are not shown properly. »find« becomes »nd«, »first« becomes »rst«. and I receive this error

```
'package inputenc error :unicode char \u8 not set up for use with latex
```

I am writing my thesis now and here is the code. Is there a problem with it please?   I have tried TeXnicCenter and TeXStudio and it doesn't help.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}      % Use the Thesis Style
\graphicspath{{F:\PhD\Latex}}   % Location of your graphics files
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square,compress]{natbib}            % Use Natbib style for the refs.
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}         %to plot figure
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}     %to use \toprule and \bottomrule without error message
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{subfigure}        % to add subfigures
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}  %to prevent word breaking
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\head}[1]{\textbf{#1}}   %to make heads of table in BOLD, it is used with booktabs package and \head
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{url} \makeatletter \g@addto@macro{\UrlBreaks}{\UrlOrds} \makeatother
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{slashbox}
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you coy/pasted "find", "first", etc. from some utf-8 encoded source, and thus the input is not the letters "f·i·n·d" but instead "ﬁ·n·d" (the first one is Unicode "LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI" U+FB01)

Comment: Does `ecsthesis` load any specific fonts?  Perhaps `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` helps.  You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) which illustrates your problem.  Because I don't have the `ecsthesis` class and your example has no content I cannot reproduce.  Also you should watch out for package clashes as you load some packages multiple times.

Comment: As @JLDiaz says, copy and pasting from some other source is most likely what has happened. The best way to solve it is to fix your *source* file by removing those characters and replacing them with the non-ligature versions.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. When I deleted find and wrote it again, it is shown properly now. Should I do the same with all ligature words ? or there is a way to fix this without deleting and rewriting every word has fi ??

Comment: Words you type normally should not pose a problem, but text you copy from a PDF for example, may cause such problems. Presumably your editor has a global replace function which can quickly change the ligatures with their their proper character combinations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add declarations for such inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FB01}{fi}
\begin{document}
ﬁnd


\end{document}
```